# Is it possible to upgrade from IE6 straight to IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-6

I.E will this work? http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=43

Comment: What's more, you can upgrade from IE6 all the way to Chrome in a single giant bound!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can skip the upgrade to Version 7 Safely. The IE 8 download was created to account for that situation.

Answer (score 0):

see this

> http://www.ehow.com/how_6794418_upgrade-ie6-ie8.html

but i don't suggest to do this, you may lose your favourities but if you don't care, try this link